# Place element outside the controller and have them still work AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

How can I control variables and elements using filters that are outside the controller?

I have set up an example to better help me explain my question http://embed.plnkr.co/7E5Ls3oH0q4HuEZsewJL/

You will see I have a div that is being toggled using ng-show and then inside a search input that filters a list of names. The problem arrises when I need to take the toggled div and the search filter  and put it outside the 'MainCtrl'. Is there a way that I can have these sitting outside the controller but still interacting with the content of the 'MainCtrl'?

Comment: I'm not being facetious here... can you think of a reason why you can't package the component into a directive and move anything data related to a service so you don't have to rely on sharing data/functionality from a single controller? That was my first thought.

Comment: No reason other than I didn't know that was possible. I'm only just starting to learn angular, so I am still getting my head into directive, factories and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to communicate between components which aren't prototypically linked in your app. You could use Angular events to broadcast your search and then handle it from your controller. Or, you could even use `$rootScope` in both components as a global space both can use to store variables and methods. These are bad ideas - they will make your life harder down the road.

Instead, whenever you need to share information across controllers and/or directives which aren't directly linked, your first thought should to create a service.

Such a service might look like this:

```
app.factory('Search', function() {
  var search = {
    results: [],
    query: '',
    showDetails: false
  };

  return search;
});
```

You would inject it into both the controller and the controller or directive (I chose to create a directive) for the search box and initialize the service to a scope variable in each:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, friendsFactory, Search) {
  $scope.friends = friendsFactory.query();
  $scope.search = Search;
});

app.directive('search', function(Search){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'directive-search.html',
    link: {
    pre: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.search = Search;
    }
    }
  }  
});
```

You could use that variable in your views, as the model for the search box and the filter for your `ng-repeat`:

**Directive Template**

```
<div ng-class="'details'" ng-show="search.showDetails">
  <label for="">Search Names</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="search.query" />
</div>
```

**Filter**

```
<div class="content" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <a ng-click="search.showDetails = !search.showDetails"> Click Me</a>
  <div ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:search.query | limitTo: 5">
    {{friend.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zJYMR2tOQO0pOFw8LmoQ?p=preview)

**Note:** this simple implementation allows for one individual search/results pair on the page. If you need to have more than one, you will need to further develop the service to allow for more than one instance.